# Unable to save an Excel file to a folder in php

Tags: php, spreadsheet-excel-writer

I am using `excelwriter.class.php` library to create an Excel file and to write data into it. This is my code:

```
<?php
include("excelwriter.class.php");

$excel=new ExcelWriter("C:/wamp/www/dbpro file/one/newfile/report.xls");
if($excel==false)   
echo $excel->error;

$myArr=array("S.No.","Student nameNumber","DOB","Subject","mark");
$excel->writeLine($myArr);
?>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function download()
{
    window.location='C:\wamp\www\dbpro file\one\newfile\report.xls';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center"><a href="javascript:void(0);"     onClick="download();">Download Excel Report</a></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

the above code is creating the Excel file with the name `report.xlsx` but the problem is it is not stored in the given path.. it is stored in the folder where my php files are stored

Below is the library I am using

```
<?php
 /*
 * Class is used for save the data into microsoft excel format.
 * It takes data into array or you can write data column vise.
 */
Class ExcelWriter
{

    var $fp=null;
    var $error;
    var $state="CLOSED";
    var $newRow=false;

    /*
    * @Params : $file  : file name of excel file to be created.
    * @Return : On Success Valid File Pointer to file
    *           On Failure return false  
    */

    function ExcelWriter($file="")
    {
        return $this->open($file);
    }

    /*
    * @Params : $file  : file name of excel file to be created.
    *           if you are using file name with directory i.e. test/myFile.xls
    *           then the directory must be existed on the system and have permissioned properly
    *           to write the file.
    * @Return : On Success Valid File Pointer to file
    *           On Failure return false  
    */
    function open($file)
    {
        if($this->state!="CLOSED")
        {
            $this->error="Error : Another file is opend .Close it to save the file";
            return false;
        }   

        if(!empty($file))
        {
            $this->fp=@fopen($file,"w+");
        }
        else
        {
            $this->error="Usage : New ExcelWriter('fileName')";
            return false;
        }   
        if($this->fp==false)
        {
            $this->error="Error: Unable to open/create File.You may not have permmsion to write the file.";
            return false;
        }
        $this->state="OPENED";
        fwrite($this->fp,$this->GetHeader());
        return $this->fp;
    }

    function close()
    {
        if($this->state!="OPENED")
        {
            $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
            return false;
        }   
        if($this->newRow)
        {
            fwrite($this->fp,"</tr>");
            $this->newRow=false;
        }

        fwrite($this->fp,$this->GetFooter());
        fclose($this->fp);
        $this->state="CLOSED";
        return ;
    }
    /* @Params : Void
    *  @return : Void
    * This function write the header of Excel file.
    */

    function GetHeader()
    {
        $header = <<<EOH
            <html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
            xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

            <head>
            <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
            <meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>
            <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
             <o:DocumentProperties>
              <o:LastAuthor>Sriram</o:LastAuthor>
              <o:LastSaved>2005-01-02T07:46:23Z</o:LastSaved>
              <o:Version>10.2625</o:Version>
             </o:DocumentProperties>
             <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
              <o:DownloadComponents/>
             </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            </xml><![endif]-->
            <style>
            <!--table
                {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
                mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";}
            @page
                {margin:1.0in .75in 1.0in .75in;
                mso-header-margin:.5in;
                mso-footer-margin:.5in;}
            tr
                {mso-height-source:auto;}
            col
                {mso-width-source:auto;}
            br
                {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
            .style0
                {mso-number-format:General;
                text-align:general;
                vertical-align:bottom;
                white-space:nowrap;
                mso-rotate:0;
                mso-background-source:auto;
                mso-pattern:auto;
                color:windowtext;
                font-size:10.0pt;
                font-weight:400;
                font-style:normal;
                text-decoration:none;
                font-family:Arial;
                mso-generic-font-family:auto;
                mso-font-charset:0;
                border:none;
                mso-protection:locked visible;
                mso-style-name:Normal;
                mso-style-id:0;}
            td
                {mso-style-parent:style0;
                padding-top:1px;
                padding-right:1px;
                padding-left:1px;
                mso-ignore:padding;
                color:windowtext;
                font-size:10.0pt;
                font-weight:400;
                font-style:normal;
                text-decoration:none;
                font-family:Arial;
                mso-generic-font-family:auto;
                mso-font-charset:0;
                mso-number-format:General;
                text-align:general;
                vertical-align:bottom;
                border:none;
                mso-background-source:auto;
                mso-pattern:auto;
                mso-protection:locked visible;
                white-space:nowrap;
                mso-rotate:0;}
            .xl24
                {mso-style-parent:style0;
                white-space:normal;}
            -->
            </style>
            <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
             <x:ExcelWorkbook>
              <x:ExcelWorksheets>
               <x:ExcelWorksheet>
                <x:Name>srirmam</x:Name>
                <x:WorksheetOptions>
                 <x:Selected/>
                 <x:ProtectContents>False</x:ProtectContents>
                 <x:ProtectObjects>False</x:ProtectObjects>
                 <x:ProtectScenarios>False</x:ProtectScenarios>
                </x:WorksheetOptions>
               </x:ExcelWorksheet>
              </x:ExcelWorksheets>
              <x:WindowHeight>10005</x:WindowHeight>
              <x:WindowWidth>10005</x:WindowWidth>
              <x:WindowTopX>120</x:WindowTopX>
              <x:WindowTopY>135</x:WindowTopY>
              <x:ProtectStructure>False</x:ProtectStructure>
              <x:ProtectWindows>False</x:ProtectWindows>
             </x:ExcelWorkbook>
            </xml><![endif]-->
            </head>

            <body link=blue vlink=purple>
            <table x:str border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style='border collapse: collapse;table-layout:fixed;'> EOH;
        return $header;
    }

    function GetFooter()
    {
        return "</table></body></html>";
    }

    /*
    * @Params : $line_arr: An valid array 
    * @Return : Void
    */

    function writeLine($line_arr)
    {
        if($this->state!="OPENED")
        {
            $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
            return false;
        }   
        if(!is_array($line_arr))
        {
            $this->error="Error : Argument is not valid. Supply an valid 
        Array.";
            return false;
        }
        fwrite($this->fp,"<tr>");
        foreach($line_arr as $col)
            fwrite($this->fp,"<td class=xl24 width=64 >$col</td>");
        fwrite($this->fp,"</tr>");
    }

    /*
    * @Params : Void
    * @Return : Void
    */
    function writeRow()
    {
        if($this->state!="OPENED")
        {
            $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
            return false;
        }   
        if($this->newRow==false)
            fwrite($this->fp,"<tr>");
        else
            fwrite($this->fp,"</tr><tr>");
        $this->newRow=true; 
    }

    /*
    * @Params : $value : Column Value
    * @Return : Void
    */
    function writeCol($value)
    {
        if($this->state!="OPENED")
        {
            $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
            return false;
        }   
        fwrite($this->fp,"<td class=xl24 width=64 >$value</td>");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Firstly you need to clarify what exactly lib you're using. May be provide a link to that lib? Secondly you need to use the `file:///` protocol: `window.location='file:///C:\wamp.......`

Comment: @Yaroslav hi , sorry i dont have link to the lib i m using but i have added the lib source code

Answer (score 0):

Wild stab in the dark.... can you use location.href to send it to the new location if you inserted it in after the document was created as it goes to download?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to invoke `close()`

Delete xls file in directory with your php file and run script again.